# Add Custom action to VS 2008 Setup project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Im using VS 2008 and I have created an application and Setup file using C#. The setup file contain only standard setup interfaces provide by visual studio 2008. I need to check windows registry and get some folder path and copy some files to my application folder while installation. Simply I need to add custom code while installation. 
Standard interfaces.

> 1. Welcome
> 2. Installation Folder
> 3. Confirm Installation
> 4. Progress
> 5. Finished I need.
> 6. Welcome
> 7. Installation Folder
> 8. Confirm Installation
> 9. Progress
> 10. MY Custom ACTION INTERFACE
> 11. Finished

MY Custom Action performs the below action.

Ex: Get registry path.

```
object test=  Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Kofax Image Products\\Ascent Capture\\3.0"
                ,"ExePath",null)

If(test!=null)
{
///Copy some files to my application folder from test path.
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: sorry. Its Windows application.

Answer (score 2):

You can **always create your own custom action** (based on **existing panels** for the UI)

Take a look at **Scott's** post entry [on the subject](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/15/tip-trick-creating-packaged-asp-net-setup-programs-with-vs-2005.aspx)

you can find there **how to create a Setup project** and **add a custom action** to it.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a [custom action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cdb5eda%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), although you wouldn't have an interface in the setup for it. It is "just" code.