# Delete event log when installer get uninstalling

Tags: c#

I was create a windows service which internally create custom event log,when service get starts.Creation of event log working perfectly but when i want to uninstall the service i am not be able to delete the custom event log from the system.

can any body have any suggestion or help about that,

thanks in advance

Comment: how are you installing? using a Setup Project?

Comment: @balexandre yes i am installing windows service using the setup project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a Setup Project, then it's quite easy to perform custom actions to your setup project.

I have answer this myself before

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5039079/28004

you simply follow up [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/15/tip-trick-creating-packaged-asp-net-setup-programs-with-vs-2005.aspx), and if you have any other questions, let me know as I use this techniques in 2 projects of mine...

This are the **2 methods** that I'm overriding:

```
protected override void OnAfterInstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
    base.OnAfterInstall(savedState);

    // your code here

    // to simple test if it runs:
    MessageBox.Show("Everything OK!", "After Install", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}

protected override void OnAfterUninstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
    base.OnAfterUninstall(savedState);

    // your code here

    // to simple test if it runs:
    MessageBox.Show("Everything OK!", "After Uninstall", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

wrap up in a new class that inherits `Installer` and set the `RunInstaller` attribute, like:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class YourInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    // code above here
}
```

**Add the output** to your setup project as `Primary Output of YourInstaller (Active)`

and **add to both actions** in the **Custom Actions** panel in your Setup Project

[image]

Then, **create the installer** and install it, at the end of the install, you will get the message box, as well when you uninstall.

Comment: thanks balexandre for reply,i was tried your way but it will not executing the uninstaller event to perform action.Is there any other way you know please suggest me. thanks

Comment: thank you balexandre,your OnAfterInstall method work perfectly for me and it removes all the previous entries of event source at the time of installation of service,and obvious your answer also.Many many thanks :)